# Implementing 2 abstract classes with a common function?

Tags: c++

What happens when a class inherits from multiple abstract classes when 2 or more of them have a function with the same name, return type, and arguments?

Assuming all functions here are virtual

Thanks

class C inherits from A and B at the same time and both A & B have virtual void func(int h);

Comment: does C contain another implementation of func()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you mean,

```
#include <iostream.h>
 class A
 {
 public:
     virtual void a_show()=0;
     virtual void show()
     {
         cout<<"A";
     }
 };
 class B
 {
 public:
     virtual void b_show()=0;
     virtual void show()
     {
         cout<<"B";
     }
 };
 class C : public A, public B
 {   
     virtual void a_show()
     {}
     virtual void b_show()
     {}
 };
 void main()
 {
     C s;
     s.show();
 }
```

The code gives an error with VC++ like

```
error C2385: 'C::show' is ambiguous
```

You need to declare show like this :

```
#include <iostream.h>
 class A
 {
 public:
     virtual void a_show()=0;
     virtual void show()
     {
         cout<<"A";
     }
 };
 class B
 {
 public:
     virtual void b_show()=0;
     virtual void show()
     {
         cout<<"B";
     }
 };
 class C : public A, public B
 {   
 public:
     virtual void a_show()
     {}
     virtual void b_show()
     {}
     void show()
     {
         cout<<"C";
     }
 };
 void main()
 {
     C s;
     s.show();
 }
```

This sure will give C

Answer (score 0):

C++ also allows to pick an inherited virtual member function (IVMF) as well, so you don't need to override an IVMF. Borrowing the example from mihsathe, we can do the following:

```
class C : public A, public B {   

  public:

    virtual void a_show() { }

    virtual void b_show() { }

    using B::show;
    // using A:show; // If you want to use show() from A
};
```